# Xcode Error When Launching Terminal

Tags: terminal, xcode

I'm getting the following errors when launching my terminal, seemingly out of nowhere. I have no idea what the cause is.

> 2022-03-23 09:41:00.818 xcodebuild[2352:21059] Requested but did not
> find extension point with identifier
> Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
>
> 2022-03-23 09:41:00.818 xcodebuild[2352:21059] Requested but did not
> find extension point with identifier
> Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore

Does anybody know how I can go about fixing this please?

Comment: What is your default shell and what is in your shell startup files?

Comment: I have somilar messages now and then. Sometimes it helps to rerun xcode-select.

Comment: I'm having the same error Today for the first time ever. And I use the Iterm2 terminal almost every single day.

Comment: @nohillside I have this message every first run of my terminal.  And no, xcode-select definitely does NOT solve it.

Comment: installing new macOS 12.4, resolved my issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This happens with XCode after every upgrade.

So, like @Eljay, I placed the following commands in a script, `upgrade-xcode-cli-tools`, which I call after each XCode upgrade:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# remove old CommandLineTools
# to force upgrade
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

# install latest
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Note that the script will cause a pop-up that requires user participation (e.g. accepting EULA). I am not aware of any way around this.

Comment: Warning: The install this requires is *extremely slow* (~3 hours on a 15mb/s connection). Make sure you can wait.

Comment: For me it took only 30min. It would depends on your network speed.

Answer (score 71):

Neither "installing components" via Xcode, nor resetting the developer directory using `sudo xcode-select -r` worked for me. However,

```sh
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

worked. Thanks to [Royite on Apple's Developer Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698628?answerId=707435022#707435022) for this solution.

Comment: this worked for me, for Xcode 13.3 macOS 12.2.1 (21D62), iterm2

Comment: I had to `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` then `sudo xcode-select --install`, and that fixed the issue for me.  (Got the recommendation hint from `brew doctor`.)

Comment: After I did this, I could no longer run `xcrun xcodebuild` from the command line. `brew doctor` says everything is fine. However, terminal and most command line tools run fine (thanks to `sudo xcode-select -r`). However `xcrun xcodebuild` generates both this error and another about "Class ... is implemented in both ...".

Comment: worked for me, Xcode command line tools on macOS v12.3.1

Comment: Also received warning: Usage of /Users/me/Library/org.swift.swiftpm/collections.json has been deprecated. Please delete it and use the new /Users/me/Library/org.swift.swiftpm/configuration/collections.json instead. As advised, delete of the deprecated file obviated the warning.

Answer (score 18):

This happened to me after an Xcode version update.  Running XCode app and letting it re-install components resolved the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "letting it re-install components?" Did this happen automatically, or did you have to select a menu item or otherwise trigger it?

Comment: Should happen automatically when running XCode first time after update.  (Unless XCode is somehow "stuck")

Answer (score 9):

**Solution:**

1. Close the terminal (it was Iterm2 in my case).
2. Just open Xcode.
3. It will request to instal additional components. Press on 'Install'.
4. When it ends, close XCode.
5. Open the terminal again. No more error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Running each one of these commands twice fixed it for me. This outputs your current sdk paths.

The errors appear on the first run, and after the second run, they magically disappear for good.

```sh
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-platform-version
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-platform-version
xcrun -sdk watchos --show-sdk-path
xcrun -sdk watchos --show-sdk-version
xcrun -sdk watchos --show-sdk-build-version
xcrun -sdk watchos --show-sdk-platform-path
xcrun -sdk watchos --show-sdk-platform-version
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320584/flutter-build-ios-got-error-requested-but-did-not-find-extension-point-with-ide

Answer (score -1):

The easy solution is if you are building react native app.
just run the command below.

react-native run-ios

Comment: The question is about Xcode errors in Terminal. Can you explain how the command you propose solves those?