# Why do I get these xcodebuild error messages about missing extension points when I run `man`?

Tags: macos, xcode

When I run something that requires command line developer tools (might be something as simple as `man`) I get a short timeout and some error messages before the command completes.

```
% man softwareupdate
2022-08-01 23:27:50.771 xcodebuild[1484:11020] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-08-01 23:27:50.771 xcodebuild[1484:11020] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

I am running macOS 12.5 and Xcode 13.4.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Xcode. If you delete the app, the command line tools work without complaint.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/439006/5472

Either a new `xcodebuild` is needed to not look for those two extensions in the plug in or the plug in needs them added.

I have not filed a feedback, but the delay is quite aggravating. When I need Xcode again, [I will try removing the watch simulator and/or downloading it completely](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/443627/5472). Perhaps there’s a workaround I have missed or I didn’t type all the above commands correctly.